# Is it possible (officially or by hack) to have Family Safety on a Win 8.1 phone?

Tags: apps, parental-control

Can it be done? I have just bought a BLU Jr and am curious if Family Safety will work on it because I read some people complaining that it doesn't work for Windows Phone yet. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 5):

Family Safety **is** available for Windows Phones, however, if you are used to the desktop version, is severely limited.

In the phone version you can limit a child phone to download any kind of apps, free apps only, or prevent them from downloading apps.

https://familysafety.microsoft.com/

Comment: I agree thank you to much so pleased that great